# 13172:13172:0130/132851.112358:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(238) Missing X server or $DISPLAY in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Okay, so I'm fairly new to using puppeteer in JavaScript, so I apologize for my inexperience. I'll try my best to stay up to date with this forum and provide any extra information that is asked of me, but I'm a CS student, so please be patient.

So I've set up Puppeteer on both my desktop computer at home and my personal laptop that I take with me, but my laptop has been having issues ever since I've tried getting it up. My desktop executes my personal project's code perfectly fine with no errors or issues in a chromium headful browser. My laptop though seems to have been having the same error, which I believe has to entirely do with the way I downloaded it.

Here is an example of something I'm trying to do:

```
const { executablePath } = require('puppeteer');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')

const url = "https://www.google.com/"

async function createPage() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, executablePath: executablePath(), args: ['--disable-web-security', '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    return page;
}

async function openPage(page) {
    await page.goto(url);
}

async function screenshot_photo(page) {
    await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.jpg'});
    await page.close()
}

async function testing() {
    var page = await createPage();
    await openPage(page);
    await screenshot_photo(page);
}

testing();
```

My error in my terminal is as follows:

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[16533:16533:0130/140329.896545:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(238)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[16533:16533:0130/140329.896887:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
```

Other useful info:

- I'm running my code in WSL: Ubuntu on both systems
- Node version: v19.1.0
- npm version: 9.3.1
- echoing display gives me me a blank output

Just to elaborate, the code I've written above works perfectly fine on my desktop with no issues.

I've tried troubleshooting this issue for quite a while and believe I might have an idea of what the issue is, but unsure what approach to take. When I originally tried to get puppeteer on my laptop, I came across many different errors and issues before I finally landed on the dreaded $DISPLAY error.

I've tried reinstalling node, npm and puppeteer many times. I've tried manually installing a chromium (PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD) and changing the executablePath to where the browser downlaoded. I tried switching to different versions of puppeteer. All these attempts lead me to worse errors and I felt would be counterintuitive since everything works fine on my desktop. The code I provided works perfectly fine headless and even screenshots the webpage, but with my project, I really need a headful display.

My idea is that there was an issue with my installation and that's the reason why I can't have my headful browser display to my screen on my laptop. So any help in reinstalling everything from the ground up, fixing my $DISPLAY, or just walking me through it would be greatly appreciated as I'm still trying to learn!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why run in WSL?,  but if you are going to go down that route, your going to have to enable GUI in WSL, maybe this will help -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

Comment: Thank you, Keith! I just prefer a Linux environment since a couple of my professors have taught in it and I've grown to like it, so it's mere preference. Nothing functional. I'll most likely make a full switch to Linux in the future.

But I appreciate the help and this has seemed to fix my display issue and has taught me a lot along the way. It makes sense, but it was just confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I much prefer Linux, but with node.js been cross platform it just seems more logical to run native than running inside WSL.  From my experience with hyper-v its a resource hog, pretty much like everything Windows.  :)

Comment: Hello DogeLovesHipster, did you get any solution for this error ... i also trying start windoes node application using ubuntu getting same error

Comment: Yeah! The solution that Keith provided worked for my WSL environment. I simply followed the instructions that were located in the link with the graphics drivers of my laptop, which were Intel, and it was able to automatically find my executablePath with how I set it up in my code. It might vary for users depending on graphics, environments, and how you call the DISPLAY within your code. My desktop computer which has a dedicated Nvidia graphics card never encountered this problem, so I would go to the link to enable GUI in WSL for an attempt at a fix first.